# Google Map does not show marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to add some markers in google map. first I put a marker in my device's current location. it works fine. but when I want to add another marker it does not show any marker. Here is the code that I tried:

```
if(isLocationEnabled(this)){
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocatoin();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            LatLng location = new LatLng(23.742801, 90.432196);
            addMarker(location,"Bashabo");

        }else {
            getLocationPermission();
        }
    }
```

Here is the getDeviceLocation() method:

```
private void getDeviceLocatoin(){
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionGranted){
            Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG,"onComplege : Found Location");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location)task.getResult();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude()))
                                .title("Marker in current location")).showInfoWindow();
                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude()),13);

                        Log.d(TAG,"onComplege : Current Location is null");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation : Security Exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is the addMarker() method:

```
private void addMarker(LatLng position, String title){
    MarkerOptions location = new MarkerOptions();
    location.position(position);
    location.title(title);
    mMap.addMarker(location).showInfoWindow();
}
```

Please help me with that

Answer (score 0):

It shows the marker when you launch the app because you gave exact lat and lng in code. The reason why it doesn't show any new marker might be that you don't turn on location services or wifi when using app. Try doing it on your device and let me know if it works.

Comment: I turned my WiFi and Location before launching the app. But it doesn't work